# Problema información inicio se pone enzima de las demás pestañas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, web

este es una parte (HTML pestaña) donde tengo el código con las pestañas y todo el inicio

```
  <body class="bodya">
  <header>
    <div><img src="img/Logo.png" class="logo"></div>
    <div><img src="img/Logo2.png" class="logo2"></div>
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="home.html" target="iframe-pestanas" class="boton"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> 
   Home</a>
        <a href="procesos.html" target="iframe-pestanas" class="boton"><i class="fas fa-beer"></i> 
   Proceso</a>
        <a href="productos.html" target="iframe-pestanas" class="boton"><i class="fab fa-product- 
   hunt"></i>Productos</a>
        <a href="contacto.html" target="iframe-pestanas" class="boton"><i class="fas fa-address- 
   book"></i>Contacto</a>
        <a href="javascript:abrir()" class=" login"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Login</a>
    </div>
 </header>
 </div>
 <iframe name="iframe-pestanas" class="con"></iframe>

 <div class="home">
    <h1>Bienvenido</h1>
    <p>
        Bienvenido a nuestra página de <b>Suprema Beer</b>
        Aquí encontrará toda la información sobre nuestra cervecería <br>y podrá ponerse en contacto 
   con nosotros.
    </p><br>

    </div>
```

y este es el otro html (home)

```
 <body class="bodyb">
 <div class="homeb">
    <h1>Bienvenido</h1>
    <p>
        Bienvenido a nuestra página de <b>Suprema Beer</b>
        Aquí encontrará toda la información sobre nuestra cervecería <br>y podrá ponerse en contacto 
     con nosotros.
    </p><br>
```

bueno lo que pretendo hacer es:

al entrar a la web aparezca de este modo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si quiero ingresar a otra pestaña me aparezca así ( modifique la imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero la realizad me aparece asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces el texto de (HTML pestaña) me queda fijo , como podría hacerlo desaparecer, al momento que yo quiera seleccionar otra pestaña(proceso-producto o contacto)

quizá lo que aplique no es lo correcto . cree un HTML (pestañas) con todo como se aprecia en la primera imagen y cree otro HTML (home) que solo aparece el texto

quizá se podrá solo mantener un solo HTML (pestañas) , que cuando inicio la pagina salga bien como la primera imagen y que cuando seleccione otro como contacto aparezca solo lo creado en ese HTML.

espero que se haya entendido

saludos

Comment: ¿Por qué usas un `iframe` para mostrar las diferentes páginas? ¿No puedes hacerlo con enlaces normales que te redirijan a los demás apartados de tu sitio?

Comment: Por si quieres mantener tu estructura de pestañas, prueba a añadirle los estilos `background-color: #FFF;` y `z-index: 999;` a tu elemento `iframe`, parece que lo está colocando por debajo del texto. Si el `z-index` no te funciona añádele también el estilo `position: relative;`.